# Change the Particualy string value without string comparison in a file using Command line Ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I want to create a shell script to  change the string values which is after **'='** in my file Using **command line**.
File is like:

```
 String name = "Max";
 String age = "24";
 String address = "Noida";
```

Or

```
String name=Max
String age=24
String address=Noida
```

But here, I don't wanna string comparison, Like this:

```
$ sed -i 's/Max/Aman/gI' String.txt
$ sed -i 's/24/25/gI' String.txt
$ sed -i 's/Noida/Delhi/gI' String.txt
```

Please suggest how to change the string values without string comparison in a file using command line.

Comment: Like this cmd, **sed -i 's/Max/Aman/gI' String.txt** ..... It checks if file has 'Max' then replace the 'Max' with 'Aman'.

Comment: Like in normal language if we want to the change any string value, we simply write name = "Aman". That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this single `sed` that doesn't check previous value while replacing with new ones:

```
sed '/name = /s/"[^"]*"/"AMAN"/; /age = /s/"[^"]*"/"25"/; /address = /s/"[^"]*"/"Delhi"/;' String.txt
```

```
String name = "AMAN";
String age = "25";
String address = "Delhi";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @anubhava Sir. Working very well.